# Kafka Connect SFTP sink - file at given time

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Is it possible to setup Kafka Connect SFTP Sink to produce files at given time?
Example - messages are produced to topic at random times, but file is generated from the messages only at one certain time point during the day. Messages that are produced after this time point wait for consumption until next time point.